# PostgreSQL - Ordering by a converted string

Tags: postgresql, date, sqlite

Brand new to PostgreSQL, but very familiar with T-SQL.  I need to write two very simple queries that return the oldest and newest dates from a date_column within a table.  The date_column is in TEXT format "mm/dd/yyyy" (it just *is*).  I am attempting to do this in PostgreSQL using my prior knowledge from T-SQL.  For the newest date, this query correctly gives me the answer:

```
select date_column
from my_table
order by date(date_column) desc limit 1;
```

However, modifying the query by either changing "desc" to "asc" or removing the qualifier altogether gives me the same answer as the newest date.

What is going on here?  I feel like even though I got the correct answer for the newest date, the syntax is the incorrect approach.  The date_column has many different values so it's not a case of me overlooking that.  I saw a very old (~2010) post using substrings to parse the date and the optimist in me believes Postgre *has* to have evolved since then :)

Cheers for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select date_column
from stringdates
order by to_date(date_column, 'MM/DD/YYYY') desc limit 1;

select date_column
from stringdates
order by to_date(date_column, 'MM/DD/YYYY') limit 1;
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/55bf7/7/8)

you can also check out these [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-formatting.html)